(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('0.97982854')
I have some questions about this error with Springbot Java 17 that appears in the console and that I have not been able to resolve.
I am making a simple request to a service which returns this json:
{
    "id": "81a51bdd-0088-4d03-9c2b-b0cade46e2b0",
    "project": "cb965621-e344-48ea-a8e4-251376ce116b",
    "iteration": "30a03b97-1269-44b2-a2c0-d95212b82d42",
    "created": "2024-05-16T14:45:32.686Z",
    "predictions": [
        {
            "probability": 0.97982854,
            "tagId": "d79f6f4a-a95d-4293-944d-aa13f96e8198",
            "tagName": "empty shelf"
        },
        {
            "probability": 0.01930153,
            "tagId": "fcc2eae3-b7f7-466f-8ed8-e256d658a755",
            "tagName": "Full shelf"
        },
        {
            "probability": 0.00086999265,
            "tagId": "f3662445-f00d-4d54-a4e9-43c855653e5e",
            "tagName": "It is not a winery"
        }
    ]
}

For this case I only work with the predictions array where inside you get probability and tagName.
But when I want to obtain the values I get the following in the console.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of com.example.prueba.model.Predictions (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('0.97982854')
at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 359] (through reference chain: com.example.prueba.model.CompuVisionResponse["predictions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
This is my class code:
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CompuVisionResponse {
   List<Predictions> predictions;
}
#######
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Predictions {
     double probability;
     String tagName;
}
#######
@Data
public class DataBodega {
     double probability;
     String tagName;
}

This is the method where I call the API to obtain the data
 @Override
    public List<List<DataBodega>> getDataBodegaModulo1(List<String> urlBodegas) {
        List<List<DataBodega>> dataListBodegas = new ArrayList<>();
        List<DataBodega> o;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set(Constants.PREDICTIONS_KEY, subscriptionkey);

        for (String url: urlBodegas){
                RequestCompuVisionModel requestModel = new RequestCompuVisionModel();
                requestModel.setURL(url);
                log.info("KEY: " + subscriptionkey);

                HttpEntity<RequestCompuVisionModel> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestModel, headers);
                System.out.println("Data String.class: "+ restTemplate.exchange(compuVision1Url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class));
                ResponseEntity<CompuVisionResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(compuVision1Url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,CompuVisionResponse.class);

                CompuVisionResponse data = response.getBody();

                o = getData(data);
                dataListBodegas.add(o);

            }
        return dataListBodegas;
    }

    public List<DataBodega> getData(CompuVisionResponse compuVisionResponse) {
        List<Predictions> predictions = compuVisionResponse.getPredictions();
        List<DataBodega> dataListBodegas = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Predictions p : predictions) {
            DataBodega dataBodega = new DataBodega();
            dataBodega.setProbability(p.getProbability());
            dataBodega.setTagName(p.getTagName());

            dataListBodegas.add(dataBodega);
        }
        return dataListBodegas;
    }

The method always collapses when reaching
ResponseEntity<CompuVisionResponse> response = restTemplate.exchange(compuVision1Url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,CompuVisionResponse.class);
I have printed the response through the console but as a String.class and it does bring me the data
Data String.class: <200 OK OK,{"id":"616f37b2-acab-44ce-82cd-05d20c79ae50","project":"cb965621-e344-48ea-a8e4-251376ce116b","iteration":"30a03b97-1269-44b2-a2c0-d95212b82d42","created":"2024-05-16T17:06:34.065Z","predictions":[{"probability":0.97982854,"tagId":"d79f6f4a-a95d-4293-944d-aa13f96e8198","tagName":"empty shelf"},{"probability":0.01930153,"tagId":"fcc2eae3-b7f7-466f-8ed8-e256d658a755","tagName":"Full shelf"},{"probability":0.00086999265,"tagId":"f3662445-f00d-4d54-a4e9-43c855653e5e","tagName":"It is not a winery"}]},[Content-Length:"500", Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8", request-id:"616f37b2-acab-44ce-82cd-05d20c79ae50", x-envoy-upstream-service-time:"755", apim-request-id:"616f37b2-acab-44ce-82cd-05d20c79ae50", Strict-Transport-Security:"max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", x-content-type-options:"nosniff", x-ms-region:"East US", Date:"Thu, 16 May 2024 17:06:33 GMT"]>
I hope I can get the data and store it in my variables, but I get a big problem in the console that I can't solve.

It should work, if you use Double instead of double.

I tried but the same error keeps coming up, it's very strange :c

Did you look at this question? Please explain, how is it different?

Try to match the structure of CompuVisionResponse with json you got and printed. As you see response, when you print response as string, has id field, project field etc along with prediction but the class
public class CompuVisionResponse {
   List<Predictions> predictions;
}

contain predictions only.
Try to rewrite it as
public class CompuVisionResponse {
   String id;
   String project;
   String iteration;
   String created;
   List<Predictions> predictions;   
} 

and Predictions class should be
public class Predictions {
        Double probability;
        String tagName;
        String tagId;
    }


is that not a matter of ignoring fields during deserialisation that are null?

ok, but there was double, I meant you can leave it as it is. The problem is in serializing, not in the case. It will not work even there be Double

I was able to find the problem, apparently it came hand in hand with restTemplate. I changed it to test with WebClient and it worked without problems. Even so, it was very strange that it did not work with restTemplate. I thank you for your comments.
